# Is moment can be used in angular 6 application to detects the dst for the time displaying in web page

Tags: angular6, momentjs, dst, moment-timezone

Please do anybody know that there is a responsive website developed in angular6 it displays times of different time zones for example Western Europe particularly UK, NL and US particularly CA, the question is can we use Moment to display the current times of these region and can moment also handles the day light saving time features for different regions automatically

Answer (score 0):

Moment, by itself, works with the browser's local time, and UTC.

If you need to support other time zones, then you can use Moment along with the [Moment-Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on library.